# how can i hide category?

Tags: categories, query-posts

Please help me I am new baby in wordpress, how can i hide that 'course or call' category from the page..

i have var dump the variable which is passing as parameter to query_post

```
        $args = jr_filter_form();
        var_dump($args);
        query_posts($args);
```

[image]

this category is having tag_ID="65" in its url , which i have seen in wordpress dashboard, job category page 
please help me a little thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks u guys , your views help me to analyse

i have added this lines and it works thanks u all,

```
$args = array_merge(
            array(
                'job_type' => 'Jobs'
            ),
            $args
        );

        query_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want to add the following to `$args`:

`'cat' => -65`

One way to to this is to add the following line after `$args = jr_filter_form();`:

`$args['cat']= -65;`

Note the `-` will exclude that particular category ID from the results.

**Reference**: WordPress codex - [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) (see: "Exclude Categories From Your Home Page")

--

**Additional Notes:**

Admittedly, I'm not too familiar with the `jr_filter_form()`.  It seems like you are using http://www.appthemes.com/themes/jobroller/ ... they may already offer a built-in solution to customize the results, but I'm not a member so I can't tell :)

Comment: thanks , but that doesnt work

Comment: Perhaps I should've asked this from the beginning, but just for clarification - are you stating `65` is the ID for _Masters in Environmental Journalism_?  And do you just want to hide that particular category (i.e. `65`), or the entire _Course or call_ field in general?

Comment: i want to hide Course or call field not Masters in Environmental Journalism?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide categories from query on your **functions.php** file too. Try this:

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse_35077_cat_excluder' );
function wpse_35077_cat_excluder( $query ) {

    if( !empty( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) )
        return;

    if( is_home() ) // Just home page
        set_query_var('category__not_in', array( 65 ) ); // ID of the categories that should not be displayed
}
```

Change the conditional `is_home()` to the page you want to hide the category or remove line to hide the category in all pages.

Read [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) on Wordpress Codex.